# Showing values in jTable B when selecting a record in jTable A

Tags: java, sql, swing

I am trying to pass in a JTable object which has columns DiscountID and Name. I am basically trying to get a row of the first column which is selected in JTable A (a DiscountID) and upon this set data relating to this selected record in JTable B which is JTable5 in the `rs.next()` loop.

The problem I have now is that since initially `int row = table.getSelectedRow();` I'm having to set it to 0 to avoid an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but then when I run the program JTable B will show information correlating to the first record in JTable A without any selection of data by me. I don't want any information to be displayed at all in JTable B until I select a record from JTable A whilst also avoiding the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. It will be much appreciated if anyone can help me to fix this I've been trying hard to find a solution.

Here is the code to my method:

```
public static ArrayList<FlexiBand> getFlexiBands(JTable table, JTable table2) {
    ArrayList<FlexiBand> flexiband = new ArrayList<FlexiBand>();
    try {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        con = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abpp034?user=abpp034&password=120001772");

        stmt = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT UpperBound, PercentageRate FROM FlexiBand WHERE DiscountID = ?");

        int row = table.getSelectedRow();

        if (row == -1) {
            row = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < table2.getRowCount(); x++) {

                table2.setValueAt("", x, 0);
                table2.setValueAt("", x, 1);

            }

        }
        System.out.println(row); // This is printing me 0 meaning that row is still 0

        System.out.println(table.getValueAt(row, 0)); // This means that row will be equal to 0
                                                      // when it goes to the next line.
        stmt.setObject(1, table.getValueAt(row, 0));

        try {

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                FlexiBand fb = new FlexiBand();

                fb.setUpperBound(rs.getInt("UpperBound"));
                fb.setPercentageRate(rs.getInt("PercentageRate"));

                flexiband.add(fb);

            }

        } finally {

            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
                }
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
                }
            }
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return flexiband;

}
```

Here is where I call the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DiscountGUIView dgv = new DiscountGUIView();

    setDiscountNames("Fixed", dgv.getjComboBox2());
    getFlexiBands(dgv.getjTable2(), dgv.getjTable5());

}
```

in the same class as the method.

Comment: when method `getFlexiBands()` is called? `table.getSelectedRow()` returns -1 if no row is selected.

Comment: @Braj I'll put it into my question now so you can see

Comment: Why are you setting it 0? Where are you getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? If you are getting exception then just handle it, don't set it to 0. It might solve your problem.

Comment: @Braj Okay the reason why I set it to 0 because when you first call table.getSelectedRow() without setting row = 0; it value is -1 which means no row's have been selected. If I don't make it 0 then I get the exception however the problem is after is that when the program runs successfully, data is shown to me in table B of a record located at row 0 of column 0 in table A which is something I don't want. I want it to be implicit

Comment: Still I am confused, if `row=-1` then just return why are you doing any calculation in `getFlexiBands()` method. check it `int row = table.getSelectedRow(); if(row==-1) return;` in the beginning of the method.

Comment: The statements where are you getting this exception just enclose it into `try-catch` to handle it. I can't say where are you getting exception until and unless I have a look at another part of your code.

Comment: I don't really understand the part of your code where you populate table2, even when row == -1 (and then initializing row). Isn't this what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: @Braj I need to return an <ArrayList> FlexiBand object too it doesn't return an integer my method and if I do return the flexiband which is an ArrayList type object it will be empty.

Comment: @atas yes I want to avoid that just don't be mislead by that I was just trying stuff out but it just didn't work.

Comment: Just `return new ArrayList<FlexiBand>()` or `null` and handle it where this returned value is used. If no row is selected then there is no meaning of doing anything. Correct me if I am wrong. You want it to be fired on user selection.

Comment: Yep I want it to be fired on user selection

Comment: The way you describe your problem, I would just handle the exception, as mentioned above.

Comment: @Braj Sorry when you mean handle the value where the returned value is used can you please explain how. I've returned a `new ArrayList<FlexiBand>();` object. When I did Null it gave me a null pointer pointing errors in other classes.

Comment: Handle the returned value means check it whether it is empty or not. or you can say it is null or not. Put a check where you are getting `NullPointerException` before accessing returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Just do in this way. Check whether row is selected or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DiscountGUIView dgv = new DiscountGUIView();

    setDiscountNames("Fixed", dgv.getjComboBox2());
    ArrayList<FlexiBand> flexiband = null;
    if (dgv.getjTable2().getSelectedRow != -1) {
        flexiband = getFlexiBands(dgv.getjTable2(), dgv.getjTable5());
    }

    if (flexiband !=null) {
        // user selected a row, do what ever you want to do
    } else {
        // nothing is selected
        // skip other operations
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a problem with `flexiband = !null` comparison it gives incompatible types error.

Comment: Sorry, Its `flexiband != null`. Are you a `Java` guy? :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, my brain is really messed up right now I've been coding all day and for the most part fixing this and now I'm doing basic mistake. And I can't read anymore haha

Comment: Just cool down your mind, You can do it easily. Lets have a cup of coffee/tea. Take a break.

Comment: Yep, I really appreciate your help by the way. I'll update you if there are any problems :)

Comment: I think I've completely lost it with this. I'm still stuck.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I'm stuck on pretty much with the statements, I'm unsure as to what the else statement is supposed to do since the 2 if statements won't execute due to the fact that getSelectedRow() returns -1 by default and if it's not -1 does the if (flexiband != null) be just calling getFlexiBands? because really I only want to view the data in the other table.

Comment: OK at initial launch second table will be empty and when user clicks on first table will populate data in second table. Have you added click listener on first table to trigger it out?

Comment: Well I've not used a click listener. if anything I've been using a change listener.